# TextField with Form not working with macOS

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I am creating a note taking app. It uses `Form` in iOS, it looks good. But in macOS the `Form` makes it look worst.

I have tried to create a borderless `TextField`, I succeded with creating it but it didn't make a difference. Then I played with some `formStyle()` configurations but it didn't help either. I created my own `TextField`, it just made things look worse. Here is the code:

```
struct MacOSTextField: View{
    @Binding var text: String
    var displayText: String
    var body: some View{
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 0.4)
            .overlay {
                TextField(displayText, text: $text)
            }
    }
    init(_ displayText: String, text: Binding<String>) {
        self.displayText = displayText
        self._text = text
    }
}
```

Is there a way to create my own `formStyle` or `Form` for macOS?